# Button is an inline element but width is working

Tags: html, css, inline

Button is an inline element, but the width properties **work** on it. Why is that?

```css
button {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<button>asdfsdf</button>
<button>234234d</button>
```

Answer (score 22):

Most browsers display `button` elements as `inline-block` by default, according to the (not normative) [Appendix D. Default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html).

Therefore, you could expect the `width` property to work, as described in [Calculating widths and margins - Inline-block, non-replaced](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inlineblock-width).

But it's not just that. `button` elements are [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element):

> In CSS, a replaced element is an element whose representation is
> outside the scope of CSS. These are kind of external objects whose
> representation is independent of the CSS.

Therefore, they have some special behavior. For example, independently of whether they have `display: inline-block` or `display: inline`, they are sized respecting the `width` property, according to [Calculating widths and margins - Inline, replaced](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width).

It's worth noting that HTML5 forces them to be displayed as `inline-block` anyway. This is explained in [10.5.2  Bindings - The `button` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-button-element-0):

> ```
> @namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
> button { binding: button; }
> ```
>
> When the *button* binding applies to a `button` element, the element
> is expected to render as an 'inline-block' box rendered as a button
> whose contents are the contents of the element.

Comment: This answer should be top answer for any button related questions.

Answer (score 3):

See [W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) (a list of HTML4 elements' default CSS styles).

`button` is an `inline-block` element (by default) that can have a `width` set, as opposed to `inline` elements.

Comment: `display: inline` would be ignored but not `display: block` - weird :)

Answer (score 0):

Set `min-width: 300px;`.

It works to me even if the button is `inline-block`.