# Why does width apply to a button with display inline?

Tags: html, button, css

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), a `button` is an inline element.

However, button elements have [default styling](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) with `display: inline-block` (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764122/html-button-is-a-inline-element-but#27764180))

```
button, textarea,
input, select   { display: inline-block }
```

So far so good.

### However:

If I now set the button with `display:inline` - width still applies!!

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/LL369vL5/)**

```css
button,
div {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
<div>div</div>
```

Now, according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-width): `width` does not apply to inline elements (which are non-replaced)

> Applies to: all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table rows,
>   and row groups

That being the case:

Why does width still apply to an inline `button` element?

Comment: Oddly enough, `display: block` can be applied on the same button

Comment: Buttons might have a display property of `inline-block`

Comment: buttons are replaced elements like `img, textarea, input and select`

Comment: @ThePragmatick See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/LL369vL5/1/) - You see? I override the default `display:inline-block` with `display:inline` and width still applies.

Comment: some old browsers it will not work and it is as simple as that.

Comment: @web-tiki Are you sure? I thought that replaced elements where elements that cannot have inner elements. A button element is a container element that *does* accept inner elements

Comment: @Danield I found a reference but am looking for an official one

Comment: @web-tiki - No they are not replaced. A replaced element is one ["whose content is outside the scope of the CSS formatting model"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/conform.html#replaced-element) That's not the case for buttons. Their contents are fully CSS stylable and their baseline (the bottom line box of their content) leaks just the same as a inline-block span would.

Comment: @Alohci this is where I found the info : http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements still looking for something more oficial though

Comment: in the user agent stylesheet, ``button, textarea`` and some other elements have ``display: inline-block;``. Looks like the UAS overrides your ``display: inline`` even though it is not crossed out in the dev tools.

Comment: @knitevision - I don't think so. Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/LL369vL5/1/) - even if I add !important to `display:inline` - width still applies.

Comment: @Danield yes, I tried that too, also tried removing ``-webkit-appearance``, but the UAS still applied. The only possible explanation, I think.

Comment: @web-tiki - I believe sitepoint is incorrect here. But I don't believe that button is correctly described in any official (W3C) documentation. The closest is the HTML5 spec which says that [buttons should be rendered as inline-block](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/rendering.html#the-button-element-0), but that doesn't explain their behaviour when set to `display:block`.

Comment: ...As far as I can tell, is what really happens is that the rendering is done partly by the element itself (always as inline-block) and partly by an anonymous wrapper box to get the `display:block` behaviour when required. But I know of nowhere that is described.

Comment: By the way, the width is not applied to ``span``, for example. I believe it's just the default browser behaviour, and not mentioned in the w3c specs.

Comment: @Alohci I can't find anything else that would totaly confirm wether it is or not a replaced element but it would explain the behaviour when a button is set to `inline` and can still have a set width/height.

Comment: @knitevision: span is inline by default, so the behavior described is the same as quoted in the question.

Comment: Pretty sure this is just one of those things that can't be fully explained beyond "form elements have special rendering outside of spec". If `display: inline` actually made a button render inline, I don't think it would be a button anymore. While it may not be a fully replaced element (as mentioned its contents are stylable by CSS), I suspect that it still generates an atomic inline box even if you force it to `display: inline`. Atomic inlines are classified as inline replaced elements in section 10, so width and height apply as they would to any other inline replaced element.

Comment: @BoltClock - Interesting. Can you point to where in section 10 it says that atomic inlines should be classified as inline replaced elements?

Comment: @Alohci: To be precise, it's the other way around - inline blocks, inline tables and replaced inline boxes are classified as "atomic inline boxes", in [9.2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes). More broadly, anything that participates in an inline formatting context, but does not itself generate line boxes, would be considered an atomic inline. The only elements that normally generate line boxes are elements with `display: inline`, but clearly that is not what happens when you try to set it on a button.

Comment: My internet connection went down earlier. I meant what @BoltClock mentions. Buttons might have an *internal* default display of `inline-block`,which can't be overridden by **superficial `display: inline !important`.

Comment: This seems to be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27770128/1414562  EDIT: ok, just saw BoltClock's comment here

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I'm pretty sure this has to do with browser-specific rendering behavior as is so typical of form elements. What I believe is happening when you set `display: inline` on the button is... nothing. Effectively, it's the same as the typical browser default `display: inline-block`, on which the `width` property does apply.

Refer to [section 10.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property), which describes the `width` property itself. In particular it explains why exactly the `width` property does not apply to inline elements (or *inline boxes*):

> This property does not apply to non-replaced inline elements. The content width of a non-replaced inline element's boxes is that of the rendered content within them (before any relative offset of children). Recall that inline boxes flow into line boxes. The width of line boxes is given by the their containing block, but may be shorted by the presence of floats.

In short, it's because the content of inline elements resides in *line boxes*. The width of a line box cannot be controlled directly; it is determined entirely by the containing block and any incidental floats. You can see an example of line box rendering in [section 9.4.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting), which describes inline formatting contexts.

If `display: inline` actually made a button render as an inline box, [all its contents would spill over](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level) and it would no longer look, or function, like a button. It makes sense to want to prevent that from happening, and I think that's just what browsers do.

So what exactly do they do to prevent this? Is a button a replaced element? I can't say for sure. But note, in [section 9.2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes), it says:

> Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as replaced inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements) are called *atomic inline-level boxes* because they participate in their inline formatting context as a single opaque box.

Section 10 does not explicitly mention atomic inline-level boxes, but it does have sections for calculating dimensions for inline replaced elements, as well as inline-block elements whether replaced or non-replaced, all of which are considered atomic inlines as mentioned above. In all of these cases, the `width` property applies as normal if it's not `auto`.

So, while it's still debatable whether or not a button is a replaced element, it probably doesn't matter at all for the purposes of this question. But it is still *some* kind of atomic inline element, since it still participates in an inline formatting context. For what it's worth, though, it appears to shrink to fit its contents if you don't set a width, so its behavior is probably closer to that of an inline-block in that case. One could say then that the [actual value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#actual-value) of `display` becomes `inline-block`, although this is never reflected in the developer tools because the computed value does not change (again a side effect of browser-specific rendering behavior).

Comment: When i saw the question i knew you where going to answer it. You human w3 reference.

Answer (score 10):

Since like Boltclock, I don't think that there's a simple answer to this, this is as much a dump of my thoughts on the subject as an answer, but I hope it will be informative.

Although the CSS display property is superficially quite simple, it actually contains a multitude of aspects. The CSS level 3 draft spec [css-display](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-display/) captures some of this complexity, but still doesn't seem to cover it adequately.

The HTML5 spec says for [the rendering of `<button>` elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/rendering.html#the-button-element-0):

> When the button binding applies to a button element, the element is
>   expected to render as an 'inline-block' box rendered as a button whose
>   contents are the contents of the element.

An `inline-block` box has a number of aspects to it:

#### 1. An [inline-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) element

This means that it participates in a inline formatting context within a line box. It flows in sequence with other elements that are on the same line. The line box's content can be centre aligned with `text-align:center` property on its container, and the line box is shortened by avoiding floated elements.

#### 2. Applies a [width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inlineblock-width) property and the auto value is [shrink-to-fit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float)

Unlike non-replaced `display:inline` elements, the width value applies. But also, if a width value is not specified, a shrink-to-fit algorithm is applied to determine the width. This is like floated elements, or `display:table` elements, but different from `display:block` elements which are as wide as possible if no width is specified. It's also unlike replaced inline elements and replaced inline-block elements which, if no width is specified, use their intrinsic width if they have one and a default value of 300px if they don't. Shrink-to-fit is a meaningless concept for replaced elements.

#### 3. A [block-container](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) element

Block container elements are make up of a stack of line boxes. The content flows from one line box to the next and the height of the inline-block elements grows (subject to overflow) to fully contain all the line boxes.

#### 4. The baseline is the baseline of the [*last* contained line box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)

When the inline-block element contains multiple lines, its baseline is the last of those lines. This is unlike floats or `display:table-cell` elements which are also shrink-to-fit, block container elements. Floats are outside normal flow so they do not have a baseline, which `display:table-cell` elements have a baseline that is the baseline of their *first* line box. A button that has multiple lines does vertically align according this last line box rule.

---

Now, this is fine for the default display setting. and the HTML5 rendering requirement means that the used value of display for buttons is `inline-block` even when the specified value is `inline`. But it doesn't account for the behaviour when specified value is `block`. In this case, the element has a line-break before and after it, and `margin:auto` centres the box as a `display:block` element would, and is not what would be expected of `inline-block`.

However, its width for a specified value of `auto` is shrink-to-fit like inline-block, whereas the expected behaviour for `display:block` is as-wide-as-possible. As far as I know, the only display value that behaves like that is `display:table`, but there is nothing else to suggest that `display:table` is being used.

So there's nothing in the spec that I can find which matches this precisely. We can only hope that when the css-display spec gets completed, that it will cover this behaviour.

Comment: That quote from HTML5 basically confirms my suspicion that browsers will try to render a button like a button.

Comment: @BoltClock - sure, but what does "like a button" mean? Three things come to mind. One is the "atomic inline element" which means that it can't be broken across lines. This does not seem subject to being overridden by CSS. Another is the default padding and borders, which can be overridden by CSS. And then there's the application of the O/S theme for buttons which is automatically applied (in Windows, at least) providing you don't tinker with the CSS border settings of the button.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 types of element.

1. Non-replaced elements

   Replaced elements

`Button` belongs to replaced element category.

You can find more on below link.

- [Littlewebhut](http://www.littlewebhut.com/css/info_nonreplaced_replaced/)
- [SitePoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements)

So, for `button`, according to [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-width), it becomes right.

**Inline, non-replaced elements**

The `width` property does not apply. A computed value of `auto` for `margin-left` or `margin-right` becomes a used value of `0`.

**Inline, replaced elements** *(This section applies to `button`)*

A computed value of `auto` for `margin-left` or `margin-right` becomes a used value of `0`.

If `height` and `width` both have computed values of `auto` and the element also has an intrinsic `width`, then that intrinsic `width` is the used value of `width`.

If `height` and `width` both have computed values of `auto` and the element has no intrinsic `width`, but does have an intrinsic `height` and intrinsic ratio; or if  `width` has a computed value of `auto`, `height` has some other computed value, and the element does have an intrinsic ratio; then the used value of `width` is:

```
 (used height) * (intrinsic ratio)
```

If  `height` and `width` both have computed values of `auto` and the element has an intrinsic ratio but no intrinsic `height` or `width`, then the used value of `width` is undefined in **CSS 2.1**. However, it is suggested that, if the containing block's `width` does not itself depend on the replaced element's `width`, then the used value of `width` is calculated from the constraint equation used for block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow.

If `width` has a computed value of `auto`, and the element has an intrinsic `width`, then that intrinsic `width` is the used value of `width`.

If `width` has a computed value of `width`, but none of the conditions above are met, then the used value of `width` becomes `300px`.But, if `300px` is too wide to fit the device, UAs should use the `width` of the largest rectangle that has a 2:1 ratio and fits the device instead.