# Why is this button’s text centered?

Tags: css

Why is the text content of a basic `<button>` element centered vertically? After looking through the button's styles in the inspector, I have been unable to figure out which CSS property is responsible for this.

```css
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button>lorem ipsum</button>
```

[image: screenshot of button]

Comment: padding affects the position of the text in a button.

Comment: In Chrome Inspector, look for the "user agent stylesheet" application. I believe FF shows the default UA stylesheet as well.. will want to try it on "simple" HTML :} It should be possible to then play with the element stylesheet to see what base value is responsible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer is that buttons - like other form elements - have special rendering which you won't find in the user agent stylesheet in the dev tools. I once asked a pretty similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27764419/703717)

Comment: @Danield `-webkit-appearance: button;`? That's a stylesheet application itself, even if not standardized CSS.

Comment: @user2864740 there is nothing in the user agent ... you can override all of them and it will remain centred

Comment: @user2864740 I also see them, and try to override them, nothing will change

Comment: @user2864740 `-webkit-appearance: none;` does not seem to affect the vertical alignment.

Comment: @Danield yes, I think we will end up with that conclusion ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif I guess that under the hood, button elements were designed that way - with their text vertically centered ... and it makes sense too... button with their text aligned to the top or bottom would be very weird buttons

Comment: @Danield well I agree on this but what is strange that we cannot easily change the alignment using line-height or flexbox. Only padding seems to work ... I think we should add this as a strong answer to "how to align text vertically" :p

Comment: I've found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764600/what-makes-the-text-on-a-button-element-vertically-centered#34612505 which might help

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot about this behavior but can't find correct answer , just a trick

```css
    button {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      text-align: left;
      position:relative;
    }
    
    button span {
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
      width:100%;
      text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<button ><span>Example</span></button>
```

Comment: The trick is really good, but why the text is vertical aligned to middle automatically is still unanswered.

Answer (score -1):

Browsers are hardcoded to have button content vertically centered and it's not something you can modify in most browsers like Chrome. See this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34612505/5623003