# Button has different baseline behaviour

Tags: css, html

I want to equalize the appearance of anchors, span and button within a certain context:

This starts of well, but as soon as a give an explicit width and height, `<button>` behaves differently than all other tags. **Am I missing a css property to equalize?**

*(the `vertical-align` prop looked like a solution... as long as I had no explicit height...)*

[image]

**html**

```css
main>* {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(blue, .1);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 .1em;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: bottom
}
```

```html
<main>
  <button>button</button>
  <a href='#'>anchor</a>
  <a>plain</a>
  <button>button</button>
  <span>span</span>
  <button>button</button>
</main>
```

### [→ CodePen](https://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/zyeGve)

Comment: button element are very *special*, they hide a lot of surprise. They will never behave like span or link element

Comment: related/possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/q/15764600/8620333 /  https://stackoverflow.com/q/51508957/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/39957592/8620333

Comment: more magic around button : https://stackoverflow.com/q/27764419/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temani's Pointer to [this elaborate analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34612505/444255) was a good one.

**Well, there's a solution then, it seems:**

- if I refrain from defining `height`, and put the desired height into `line-height` instead
- and set `vertical-align: middle` (relevant for all tags *except* the button)

```
    overflow: hidden      
    width: 60px
    vertical-align: middle // button won't care, but everyone else
    line-height: 100px
```

**I get, what I want** (also the exact height btw, not plus some other base value)

[image]