# Why does margin-top and margin-bottom work for input?

Tags: html, css

As many sites indicate, the input tag is an inline one (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp). On the other hand, margin-top and margin-bottom must not work for inline elements (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp). While it is true for other inline elements such as spans, margin-top and margin-bottom works for inputs, which is very strange. Does anyone know why it is the case?

Comment: its an inline-block element. So its not a pure inline-element that is depending on the line height but a block element inside the line with a default height of 1em.

Comment: Thanks, @tacoshy. Yes, you're right. It seems it's inline-block in HTML5 based on this link: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-button-element-0. But why can't I override it? Even with display: inline, the margin-top also works...

Comment: you cannot force them to be inline, they are *special* element:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27765495/8620333